# Can't solve the protocol violationSMTP

Tags: node.js, sockets, smtp, nodemailer

I have this error from smtp gmail when i try to send my message.

I use TLS socket on nodejs to connect to smtp, then i have a class which creates me **commands** which i send.

```
secure.on('secureConnect', () => {
        //secure.setEncoding('base64');

        let caretka = `\r\n`;
        console.log(secure.authorized);
        console.log('IN SECURE');

        //secure.write('EHLO hailmail\r\n');
        **com**.forEach(command => {
            secure.write(command);
        });

        secure.write('quit\r\n');
        secure.on('data', chunk => {
            const response = chunk.toString();
            console.log(`Response in secure: ${response}`);

        })
        secure.on('keylog', (line) => {
            console.log(`Line in secure: ${line}`);
        })
        secure.on('close', () => {
            console.log('closed');
        })
    });
```

My class:

```
class creatingCommandsForSMTP {
constructor(msg) {
    this.helo = `EHLO hailmail\r\n`;
    this.mailFrom = `MAIL FROM: <${msg.from}>\r\n`;
    this.recipient = `RCPT TO: <${msg.recipient}>\r\n`;
    this.commandData = `DATA`;
    //this.dataFrom = `FROM: <${msg.from}>\r\n`;
    //this.dataTo = `TO: <${msg.recipient}>\r\n`;
    //this.dataSubject = `SUBJECT: ${msg.subject}\r\n`;
    //this.dataText = `${msg.text}\r\n`;
    //this.dot = `.\r\n`;
    //this.commandQuit = 'QUIT\r\n';
}
getValue(command) {
    return this[command]
}
```

};

So the problem is when i send Mail from and Rcpt to i always get OK code from server,
but after command 'DATA\r\n' i have this response:

'**451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821 k12-20020adff5cc000000b0021e4c3b2966si4569901wrp.1037 - gsmtp** '

I tried to search RFC 2821, but there is no information about rules inside the DATA command

**EDIT**: The last tries gave me a code 'Go Ahead' which means that server is ready to recieve data, then i send 'FROM: ' and get the same code '451 SMTP protocol violation'

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the right commands in the right order? It's not clear how this "command class" matches up with the sending code (which uses array "com")

Comment: There should be an empty line between mail header and body. See RFC 5322 for how a mail should look like. Also, if you get the error when sending DATA something went wrong with the previous commands. Unfortunately you don't provide any details about these responses. And you don't wait for the server response but instead blindly send commands, which is wrong unless SMTP pipelining is supported by the server.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, i have solved my problem with, now my server waits for request to make a pesponse!

Comment: user253751, yes, i was sure that my command are corrent  and that i use the right order. For now my order is solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many mail servers deliberately reject anything that does not follow the RFCs to the letter, in the aim of rejecting bots and spammers. The code snippet is obviously incomplete, but I suspect that the error you are seeing is caused because the commands you are sending do not wait for a response before sending the next. This is classic bot behaviour.

If you change your main command loop to something like the following, you should avoid this problem (psuedocode):

```
loop_through_commands {
   send command
   receive response
   if error blah
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i have solved my trouble with this!)

Comment: Cool beans: my pleasure!